# I couldn't find a tag for vaccination, though it should have been used in some questions

Tags: support, tagging

Is this the right place to ask for someone to create a new tag: vaccination

Comment: I think we normally use the health tag.

Comment: Welcome to Travel Meta Ola Ström! You have indeed come to the right place to ask for a new tag, if you don't enough reputation yet to create it yourself! Thanks for caring enough to want to add to the community!

Comment: Hi @JoErNanO! I thought the vaccination tag might be a good idea too, but upon a tag search, I found it! However, it's a [synonym of health](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/health/synonyms). I think that means anytime someone chooses "vaccination" or any of the others listed in the group of synonyms above, the system will automatically insert the "health" tag instead. I don't think the user would need to have chosen the health tag. Am I correct, or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Sue! You are indeed correct. In general we use synonyms when the number of questions or the specificity of a given tag is too low to warrant a specific tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you ask your question and add the tag which is closest, our users will add the tag that is needed. (Mods are included in users for that.)
You can ask for tag help as a last line of the question.

In case the tag needed is not yet there someone will make it.

Comment: Looks like [existing questions related to vaccination](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=vaccination+is%3Aq) are tagged with [tag:health] instead.